# How much do car hire companies charge for fuel in Paphos, Cyprus

Tags: car-rentals, fees-and-charges, cyprus

I know that all (or most) car hire firms charge you for a full tank of fuel on collection, but how much is it likely to be per litre?

Is there any limit on what they can charge or could I feasibly turn up to find that I've got to pay EUR100 per litre (standard terms say you can't cancel a reservation on the day it begins)?

Thanks

Comment: You are advised to play fuel tank roulette and return it as empty as you dare. Anything left in the tank is your loss.

Comment: I don't know about in Cyrpus, but everywhere I've ever rented a car, this varies widely by company, and the policies always favor the company, not the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd update this with my experience.

I rented through Elephant Rentacar in the end.

For 11 days' hire in November (2015) I paid EUR161. For this I got a Mondeo-sized car (Chevrolet, I think) with aircon. I had to pay EUR 45 for a half-tank of fuel. Given an assumed 50-litre tank, this was a little over the rate at the time but not obscenely so and much better than all the major brands at Paphos airport. If it was a 60-litre tank then it was probably almost the market rate.

I'd also say that it was a stress-free experience renting from them. The car had a few dints when I picked it up that were not marked onthe hire sheet (it was dark when we collected the car) but I called to discuss these and was told not to worry about them.  True to their word, they did not seem to check the car upon its return, other than it was in a decent state.

It seems like they are genuine good guys, but that's just my thoughts.

I was driving all over the island so I could plan to return it with a little bit of fuel in it. Ok, so I lost out a little there but the fairly low cost or hiring a car for 11 days seems a good tradeoff for a loss of 5 litres or so.

I would rent from them again.

Answer (score 1):

Usually they charge approx 50€ per full tank (~40 liters) and no matter how many liters left, when you get back the car.

Comment: @pnuts several companies